# Как скрыть содержимое по клику на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, jquery

После загрузки страницы на сайте появляется окно с сообщением. Как его закрыть по клику на кнопку и чтобы окно появлялось каждые 10 минут? Т.е удалить класс `fil` в body и html убрать.

```
setTimeout( function() {
    $("body").addClass('fil');
    $("html").append( "<div class='pqq'><a href='#'>Закрыть окно</a></div>" )
}, 120000);
```

Answer (score 0):

[setInterval](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval#setinterval)

```js
$(".close").on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().hide();
});

setInterval(function() {
  if ($("#window").css('display') == 'none') {
    $("#window").show();
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
#window {
  border:1px solid#000;
  padding:15px;
}

.close {
  float:right;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div id="window">
    Сообщение
    <span class="close">[X]</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: Как это с моим примером совместить?

Comment: Как html не выносить из скрипта?